# Shortest cycle in undirected weighted graph which contains every node

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Problem: Find the 'shortest cycle in undirected weighted graph which contains every node'. All weights are positive. A node may be visited more than once, the is distinguishes the problem from a Hamiltonian cycle (TSP).

A naïve attempt might be to use the minimum spanning tree (MST) and backtrack to get to the starting node. This results in a length of 2*MST but is not the minimum cycle.

Example: Consider a complete graph with vertices 1,2,3,4 and edge costs c12=c13=c14=1 and c23=c24=c34=100. TSP distance = 202 (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1). Shortest cycle distance = 6 (1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 1 -> 4 -> 1)

Edit: I am looking for an algorithm to find the shortest cycle.

Comment: Good, and your question?

Comment: I need more detail to answer your "question" (it's in quotations because no question is being asked here) — maximum number of nodes, maximum edge weight, if the graph is connected, if there are multi-edges and self-loops.

Comment: @RyanZhang  I edited the question to make it clearer. I am looking for the algorithm to find the shortest cycle. The algorithm should return the edges that form the shortest cycle.

Comment: Great. I still need more detail.

Comment: @RyanZhang Given a Graph G, what algorithm would you use to find the all the edges that form the shortest cycle that visits each node in G

Comment: Ok, please answer all the questions I put above. I need to know how many nodes there are— do you want a O(N) solution (seems unlikely)? Does the graph have special characteristics? What about O(max edge weight) or something similar?

Comment: @RyanZhang The graph can have between 1 and 100,000 nodes and between 1 and 1,000,000 edges. It does not have any special characteristics other than the edges are positive weighted (w >0) and are undirected. It has cycles (loops). The graph is fully connected, that is all nodes can be reached from any other node. I would like to know O(N) if possible.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/tsp-with-repeated-city-visits

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I was wondering if this problem is NP-hard like the TSP or if there was some clever algorithm to solve it like 'Find shortest cycle' or MST problems.

Comment: I think I found a similar question to talks about TSP with multiple visits. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269983/traveling-salesman-problem-why-visit-each-city-only-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Wikipedia page on TSP, it mentions a special case called "[metric TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Metric)", in which distances satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

In metric TSP, it does not matter whether or not you can visit the same city twice, because doing so is never necessary.  You can always easily remove all the repeated visits without making your path any longer.

Every instance of "metric TSP" is, therefore, an instance of your problem.  Metric TSP is still NP-hard, so your problem is too.

Comment: Thank you. I saw in another discussion that TSP with repeat visits (my problem) can be transformed into a TSP without the repeat visits. So an algorithm that solves TSP would also solve my problem. And that Is NP-hard. This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The proof actually needs to go the other way -- An algorithm that solves your problem also solves metric TSP, so your problem is NP-hard.  It's easy to confuse the reduction direction in these proofs.